# Nav not showing up in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am learning Aurelia and have stuck at this for quite a while. I want to add a navigation bar at the top of the screen using routing in Aurelia.

app.js:

```
export class App {

configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.map([
        {
            route: "add",
            moduleId: "./add",
            title: "Add new Post",
            nav: "true",
            name: "Add"
        }
    ]);
}
... rest of the code
```

app.html:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation">
                    <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

Nothing shows up when I load the app. The navbar remains empty. Is there any required dependency to use the router? Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Note: Not sure if this is enough context to answer my question. I can add `config.js` or any other file if it's required.

**Update**  : I replaced `${row.title}` with `hello` (any hard coded string) and it's not showing up.

Comment: What does your app.html  look like?

Comment: the html in the question refers to `app.html`, I am now wondering if I am missing something in the configuration for the `router`

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile, so sometimes I miss stuff. Try changing nav: "true" to nav: true

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that, but it's still not showing up. Really weird.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I tried your code and it looks like you need to have `<router-view></router-view>` in app.html.
And you may need to have an unnamed route (like `route: ["", "add"]`), else you'll get an error.

Comment: Take a look at the browser console. There might be some error message

Comment: Adding `router-view` fixed it. Thank you @doeck and others. If possible can someone please explain how adding that fixes my issue? I looked in the `aurelia` docs but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Great that it worked. I can't explain why, it was just try and error looking at what's different to my working solution.

Comment: My best guess(after watching Scott Allen's Pluralsight course) is it adds some kind of placeholder in html which is needed to display the nav routes. Not sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comment from `doeck` I fixed the issue. I had to do two things:

1. add a `<router-view></router-view>` tag in my app.html
2. add an empty route in my app.js as follows: `route: ["", "home"],`
   (When I didn't give the empty route, aurelia gave an error asking route      "/" is not defined.)